# Is there an identity/formula for determinant of a sparse matrix where nonzero elements shift in each row?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

I have this sparse matrix where each row has 3 nonzero elements and for every row, these 3 elements shift one column to the right. if the elements meet the end of the matrix, they appear from the first column (you can say a circular shift). for example for a $5 \times 5$ matrix
$$a_{1,1},a_{1,2},a_{1,3} \ne 0$$
$$a_{2,2},a_{2,3},a_{2,4} \ne 0$$
$$a_{3,3},a_{3,4},a_{3,5} \ne 0$$
$$a_{4,4},a_{4,5},a_{4,1} \ne 0$$
$$a_{5,5},a_{5,1},a_{5,2} \ne 0$$
where $a_{i,j}$ is the element of i-th row and j-th column. and other elements are zero. this can be generalized for a $N \times N$ matrix. I want to know is there any identity that we can use to rewrite the determinant of this matrix (or these types of matrices) in the form of product of simpler expressions (for example determinant of smaller matrices). This requirement is for computing the roots of the characteristic equation of my problem.

Comment: Are the three elements in each row the same? If so, then you have a [circulant matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circulant_matrix), and its eigenvalues can be directly computed

Comment: @BenGrossmann No they are different.